# CSS Mobile version switching back to desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have created a web page that uses media query to select a specific css (one for mobile, and one for desktop version).

```
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 640px)" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="only screen and (min-width: 641px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="medDesign.css" />
```

`medDesign.css` will be selected on a desktop version, and `mobile.css` will be selected on a mobile version.
I am also using:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,
initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'/>
```

I am using the viewport in order to show the website in a proper way using the mobile CSS file.

---

It all works very well, but now I also need that the user will have an option when surfing from mobile to switch to the desktop view.
I have not managed to do so. Because I am using media queries the css that will be picked is very absolute, and I cannot seem to control by user choice what css will be displayed.

P.S. When the user decides to switch to the desktop version, I also need to disable the viewport, because I do not want the content to be on the device's width.

Thanks alot for any light on that matter, I have searched the web but did not find a solution that fits my requirements..

Comment: Set a cookie and change the page output server side. Pseudo code: `if( !cookie.desktop ){ /* meta viewport, mobile <link> tags */ }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any example or code pieces that can assist me using the server side for that matter? May .NET Sessions replace the use of cookies? How can I combine the media queries with the server side? Sorry but I am really quite lost in here.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines of code in your webpage.

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selector').on('click',function(){
                    $('head').find('meta').each(function(index, element) {
                        if(this.name == "viewport")
                        {
                            $(this).removeAttr('content');
                            $(this).attr('content','initial-scale=0');
                        }
                    });

            });
      });

    </script>
```

**replace #selector with your selector.**

It helped me. Hope this help you.